# how to add a filter on the partition by

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I am using sql oracle.

I have a table with an emplid and an effdt. I want to add a column in my select that gives the current_flag. I thought this query will do:

```
select emplid,effdt,
    CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY emplid order by effdt desc) 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N' 
    END CURRENT_FLAG
from job_table
```

The problem is that I want a 'Y' for the **highest effdt** of an emplid, but the **effdt < sysdate**.

Example:

```
emplid  effdt
x   01/01/2014
x   01/01/2015
x   01/01/2016
y   01/01/2014
y   01/01/2015
y   01/01/2016
y   01/01/2020
```

with my query I have a 'Y'

for the X on 01/01/2014 and
for y on 01/01/2020.

But I want as result:

```
emplid  effdt   current_flag
x   01/01/2014  N
x   01/01/2015  N
x   01/01/2016  Y
y   01/01/2014  N
y   01/01/2015  N
y   01/01/2016  Y
y   01/01/2020  N
```

because 01/01/2020 is not current but in the future. 
or maybe an "F" for the value Y on the date 01/01/2020 to show it is in the Future.

I wanted to put an filter `effdt < sysdate` on my partition by, but I don't know how.

Comment: can't you try with  `WHEN 1 and effdt < sysdate THEN 'Y'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, please. It must working

If I understand task

```
   with tbl  as 
    (SELECT 'x' as id, to_date('01/01/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') as dt FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'x' as id, to_date('01/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') as dt FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'y' as id, to_date('01/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'y' as id, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'y' as id, to_date('01/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM dual)
    select id, dt, 
        CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id order by case when dt > sysdate then to_date('01/01/1970', 'dd/mm/yyyy') else dt end  desc) 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N' 
        END flg
    from tbl
```

If I understand task, you can 'F' mark date in "case":
when effdt < sysdate then 'F'

```
    with tbl  as 
    (SELECT 'x' as id, to_date('01/01/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') as dt FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'x' as id, to_date('01/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') as dt FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'y' as id, to_date('01/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'y' as id, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'y' as id, to_date('01/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM dual)
    select id, dt, 
        CASE WHEN dt > sysdate  THEN 'F'
            WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id order by case when dt > sysdate 
                then to_date('01/01/1970', 'dd/mm/yyyy') else dt end  desc) = 1 
            THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N' 
        END flg
    from tbl

x   01.01.2015  Y
x   01.01.2014  N
y   01.01.2016  Y
y   01.01.2015  N
y   01.01.2020  F
```

Comment: @BigJo . . . This does not work if the employee only has future dates.

Comment: Yes, you are rigth. Yes, You are right, but order can change: CASE WHEN dt > sysdate  THEN 'F'
                WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id order by case when dt > sysdate 
                    then to_date('01/01/1970', 'dd/mm/yyyy') else dt end  desc) = 1 
                THEN 'Y'
                ELSE 'N' 
            END flg

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
select jt.*,
       (case when max(case when effdt < sysdate then effdt end) over (partition by empid) = effdt
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end)
from job_table jt;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4504b97b2b0dbf1fe3f3d68657be730c) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that this works where Rustam's answer does not.

This assumes that the dates are unique.

If that is possible, you can use `row_number()`, but it is a little cumbersome:

```
select jt.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by empid
                                     order by case when effdt < sysdate then 1 else 2 end, effdt desc
                                    ) and
                  effdt < sysdate
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end)
from job_table jt;
```